# Native Chrome logo / icon in extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, icons, favicon

Is there a way to get a Chrome icon in extension without bundling it?

Have not found any way to access `chrome://theme` and can therefore not use e.g.:

```
chrome://theme/IDR_PRODUCT_LOGO_16
```

Even with added `chrome://favicon` to *manifest.json* these give blank icons:

```
chrome://favicon/chrome://chrome
chrome://favicon/chrome://help
```

These are examples of icons that works fine:

```
chrome://favicon/chrome://settings
chrome://favicon/chrome://bookmarks
```

But no luck finding a way to access a plain Chrome logo.

I can bundle it, but that seems rather weird.

Comment: Be careful with that. From the Web Store's developer agreement: _"Nothing in this Agreement gives Developer a right to use any of Google’s trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names, or other distinctive brand features."_ Certainly there are "fair use" scenarios, but Google may frown upon anything that can even remotely imply they endorse you.

Comment: @Xan: Thanks for input. I generate a list of tabs in window with the layout : *`[favicon] URL`*. Can't see how that would be an issue. *(I do not intend to "use" the icons, if you get what I mean.)* Problem is that various internal *Chrome pages* does not report valid icon. (Such as *about*, *developer tools*, etc.)